# Help with my first Metabox helper class

Tags: php, functions, metabox, javascript

I'm working on a metabox helper class and everything works well, but the radio image field. The images show up, but they aren't clickable.

```
        // Print radio_image input.
    private function radio_image_input( $field ) {

        $selected_value = $field['value'];

        $radio_image_field = '';
        $radio_image_field .='
                <style>
                    .optionimg{border:3px solid #cecece; margin-right:4px;cursor:pointer;}
                    .optionimg.optselected{border-color:#ababab;}
                    .form-table td em{font-style:normal;color:#999999;font-size:12px;}
                </style>
                <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery( \'.optionimg\').click(function(){
                        jQuery(this).parent().find( \'.optionimg\').removeClass( \'optselected\' );
                        jQuery(this).addClass( \'optselected\' );
                    });
                });
                </script>
            ';
        if ( ! empty( $field['choices'] ) ) {
            foreach ( (array) $field['choices'] as $value => $label )
                $radio_image_field .= sprintf(
                    '<img src="'.$label.'" class="optionimg '.$selected_value.'" onclick="document.getElementById(\''.$field['id'].$choices.'\').checked=true" style="display:inline-block;" /><input type="radio" name="%s" id="%s" value="%s" style="display:none;"/>',
                    esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                    esc_attr( $value ),
                    esc_attr( $value ),
                    esc_html( $label )
                );
        }

        return $radio_image_field;
    }
```

I think the problem is the JS, but I couldn't figure out why/where.

The full class is here:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'TheUx_Metabox_API' ) ) {

    class TheUx_Metabox_API {

        // Holds options for menu page.
        var $options = array();

        // Holds settings fields data.
        var $fields = array();

        // Supported input field types to white label while saving.
        var $supported_fields = array();

        // Holds current folder path.
        var $dir_path;

        // Holds current folder URI.
        var $dir_uri;


        function __construct( $options = array(), $fields = array() ) {

            // Set directory path.
            $this->dir_path = str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) );

            // Set directory uri.
            $this->dir_uri  = trailingslashit( home_url() ) . str_replace( str_replace( '\\', '/', ABSPATH ), '', $this->dir_path );

            // Default page options.
            $options_default = array(
                'metabox_id'    => '',
                'metabox_title' => '',
                'post_type'     => '',
                'context'       => 'normal',
                'priority'      => 'high',
            );

            $this->options = wp_parse_args( $options, $options_default );
            extract( $this->options );

            // Titles and slugs should not be empty.
            if ( empty( $metabox_id ) || empty( $metabox_title ) || empty( $post_type ) )
                return false;

            // Set input fields.
            $this->fields = (array) $fields;

            // Default field options.
            $field_default = array(
                'title'    => '',
                'type'     => '',
                'desc'     => '',
                'choices'  => array(),
                'multiple' => false,
                'sanit'    => '',
            );

            // To eliminate PHP warning we need to set default empty values.
            foreach ( $this->fields as $key => $field )
                $this->fields[ $key ] = wp_parse_args( $field, $field_default );

            // Set list of input field types. We are white labeling these field types while saving meta.
            $this->supported_fields = (array) apply_filters( 'theux_metabox_api_supported_fields', array( 
                'text', 
                'textarea', 
                'radio', 
                'radio_image', 
                'checkbox', 
                'select', 
                'multicheck', 
                'upload', 
                'color', 
                'editor' 
            ));

            add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'register_metabox' ) );
            add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_metabox' ), 10, 2 );

            add_action( 'admin_head', array( $this, 'color_picker_js' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_head', array( $this, 'upload_js' ) );
        } // end of __construct


        /**
         * HTML helper functions. 
         * A simple HTML helper functions to generate the form fields.
         */

        // Print Help/descripting for field.
        private function help_text( $field ) {
            if ( empty( $field['desc'] ) )
                return '';

            return '<p class="description">' . wp_kses_data( $field['desc'] ) . '</p>';
        }

        // Returns the form table html.
        public function get_form_table( $fields, $show_help = true ) {

            $form_table = '';
            $form_table .= '<table class="form-table">';

            foreach ( (array) $fields as $field )
                $form_table .= $this->get_table_row( $field, $show_help );

            $form_table .= '</table>';

            return apply_filters( 'theux_metabox_api_form_table', $form_table, $fields, $show_help );
        }

        // Echo/display the HTML form table.
        public function display_form_table( $fields, $show_help = true ) {

            echo $this->get_form_table( $fields, $show_help );
        }


        // Returns the table row html.
        public function get_table_row( $field, $show_help ) {

            $table_row = '<tr valign="top">';
                $table_row .= sprintf( '<th><label for="%s">%s</label></th>', esc_attr( $field['id'] ), $field['title'] );
                $table_row .= sprintf( '<td>%s</td>', $this->get_field( $field, $show_help ) );
            $table_row .= '</tr>';

            return apply_filters( 'theux_metabox_api_table_row', $table_row, $field, $show_help );
        }


        // Returns a input field based on field options.
        public function get_field( $field, $show_help = true ) {

            $field_default = array(
                'title'    => '',
                'id'       => '',
                'type'     => '',
                'default'  => '',
                'choices'  => array(),
                'value'    => '',
                'desc'     => '',
                'sanit'    => '',
                'multiple' => false, // for multiselect fiield
            );

            $field = wp_parse_args( $field, $field_default );
            $input_html = '';

            switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                case 'text'       : $input_html .= $this->text_input( $field ); break;
                case 'textarea'   : $input_html .= $this->textarea_input( $field ); break;
                case 'select'     : $input_html .= $this->select_input( $field ); break;
                case 'radio'      : $input_html .= $this->radio_input( $field ); break;
                case 'radio_image': $input_html .= $this->radio_image_input( $field ); break;
                case 'checkbox'   : $input_html .= $this->checkbox_input( $field ); break;
                case 'multicheck' : $input_html .= $this->multicheck_input( $field ); break;
                case 'upload'     : $input_html .= $this->upload_input( $field ); break;
                case 'color'      : $input_html .= $this->color_input( $field ); break;
                case 'editor'     : $input_html .= $this->editor_input( $field ); break;
            }

            if ( $show_help && 'checkbox' !== $field['type'] )
                $input_html .= $this->help_text( $field );

            return apply_filters( 'theux_metabox_api_input_field', $input_html, $field, $show_help );
        }

        // Displays a input field based field options
        public function display_field( $field, $show_help = true ) {
            echo $this->get_field( $field, $show_help );
        }


        // Print text input.
        private function text_input( $field ) {
            return sprintf(
                '<input type="text" name="%s" id="%s" value="%s" class="regular-text"/>',
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_attr( $field['value'] )
            );
        }

        // Print textarea input.
        private function textarea_input( $field ) {
            return sprintf(
                '<textarea name="%s" id="%s" rows="5" cols="40">%s</textarea>',
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_textarea( $field['value'] )
            );
        }

        // Print select input.
        private function select_input( $field ) {
            $selected_value = $field['value'];
            $multiple = ( true == $field['multiple'] || 'true' == $field['multiple'] ) ? true : false ;

            if ( $multiple )
                $field['id'] = $field['id'] . '[]';

            $select_field = sprintf(
                '<select name="%s" id="%s"%s>',
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                ( $multiple ? ' multiple' : '' )
            );

            if ( ! empty( $field['choices'] ) ) {
                foreach ( (array) $field['choices'] as $value => $label ) {
                    $selected = $multiple ? selected( in_array( $value, (array) $selected_value ), true, false ) : selected( $selected_value, $value, false );
                    $select_field .= sprintf(
                        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                        esc_attr( $value ),
                        $selected,
                        esc_html( $label )
                    );
                }
            }

            $select_field .= '</select>';
            return $select_field;
        }

        // Print checkbox input.
        private function checkbox_input( $field ) {
            return sprintf(
                '<label><input type="checkbox" name="%s" id="%s"%s> %s</label>',
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                checked( $field['value'], 'on', false ),
                __( $field['desc'] )
            );
        }

        // Print radio input.
        private function radio_input( $field ) {
            $selected_value = $field['value'];
            $radio_field = '';

            if ( ! empty( $field['choices'] ) ) {
                foreach ( (array) $field['choices'] as $value => $label )
                    $radio_field .= sprintf(
                        '<label><input type="radio" name="%s" id="" value="%s"%s> %s</label><br/>',
                        esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                        esc_attr( $value ),
                        checked( $selected_value, $value, false ),
                        esc_html( $label )
                    );
            }

            return $radio_field;
        }

        // Print radio_image input.
        private function radio_image_input( $field ) {

            $selected_value = $field['value'];

            $radio_image_field = '';
            $radio_image_field .='
                    <style>
                        .optionimg{border:3px solid #cecece; margin-right:4px;cursor:pointer;}
                        .optionimg.optselected{border-color:#ababab;}
                        .form-table td em{font-style:normal;color:#999999;font-size:12px;}
                    </style>
                    <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery( \'.optionimg\').click(function(){
                            jQuery(this).parent().find( \'.optionimg\').removeClass( \'optselected\' );
                            jQuery(this).addClass( \'optselected\' );
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
                ';
            if ( ! empty( $field['choices'] ) ) {
                foreach ( (array) $field['choices'] as $value => $label )
                    $radio_image_field .= sprintf(
                        '<img src="'.$label.'" class="optionimg '.$selected_value.'" onclick="document.getElementById(\''.$field['id'].$choices.'\').checked=true" style="display:inline-block;" /><input type="radio" name="%s" id="%s" value="%s" style="display:none;"/>',
                        esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                        esc_attr( $value ),
                        esc_attr( $value ),
                        esc_html( $label )
                    );
            }

            return $radio_image_field;
        }


        // Print multi-checkbox input.
        private function multicheck_input( $field ) {
            $selected_value = (array) $field['value'];
            $multicheck_field = '';

            if ( ! empty( $field['choices'] ) ) {
                foreach ( (array) $field['choices'] as $value => $label )
                    $multicheck_field .= sprintf(
                        '<label><input type="checkbox" name="%s[]" id="" value="%s"%s> %s</label><br/>',
                        esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                        esc_attr( $value ),
                        checked( in_array( $value, $selected_value ), true, false ),
                        esc_html( $label )
                    );
            }

            return $multicheck_field;
        }

        // Print upload input.
        private function upload_input( $field ) {

            // We require to enqueue media uploader scripts and styles.
            wp_enqueue_media();

            return sprintf(
                '<input type="text" name="%s" id="%s" value="%s" class="regular-text hd-upload-input"/>' .
                '<input type="button" value="%s" class="hd-upload-button button button-secondary" id="hd_upload_%s"/>',
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_attr( $field['value'] ),
                __( 'Upload', 'theux' ),
                esc_attr( $field['id'] )
            );
        }

        // Print color picker input.
        private function color_input( $field ) {

            // We require to enqueue color picker scripts and styles.
            wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );

            $default_color = empty( $field['default'] ) ? '' : ' data-default-color="' . esc_attr( $field['default'] ) . '"';

            return sprintf(
                '<input type="text" name="%s" id="%s" value="%s" class="hd-color-picker"%s/>',
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_attr( $field['id'] ),
                esc_attr( $field['value'] ),
                $default_color
            );
        }

        // Print tinymce editor input.
        private function editor_input( $field ) {
            $settings = array(
                'media_buttons' => false,
                'textarea_rows' => 5,
                'textarea_cols' => 45,
            );

            $content = $field['value'];
            $content = empty( $content ) ? '' : $content;

            ob_start();
            wp_editor( $content, $field['id'], $settings );
            return ob_get_clean();
        }



        /**
         * Main functions. 
         * The follow functions will register, print, save and sanitise the metabox.
         */

        // Register metabox.
        function register_metabox() {

            extract( $this->options );
            foreach ( (array) $post_type as $type )
                if ( post_type_exists( $type ) )
                    add_meta_box( $metabox_id, esc_html( $metabox_title ), array( $this, 'display_metabox' ), $type, $context, $priority );
        }

        // Print metabox content.
        function display_metabox( $post ) {

            foreach ( (array) $this->fields as $meta_key => $meta_field ) {
                $this->fields[ $meta_key ]['id'] = $meta_key;
                $this->fields[ $meta_key ]['value'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, true );
            }

            wp_nonce_field( $this->options['metabox_id'] . '_' . $post->ID, $this->options['metabox_id'] . '_' . $post->ID . '_nonce' );
            do_action( 'theux_metabox_api_metabox_before', $this->options, $this->fields );

            echo '<div class="hd-metabox-inner ' . sanitize_html_class( $this->options['metabox_id'] ) . '">';
                $this->display_form_table( $this->fields, true );
            echo '</div>';

            do_action( 'theux_metabox_api_metabox_after', $this->options, $this->fields );
        }

        // Save metabox.
        function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {

            extract( $this->options );

            if ( ! isset( $_POST[ $metabox_id . '_' . $post_id . '_nonce' ] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $metabox_id . '_' . $post_id . '_nonce' ], $metabox_id . '_' . $post_id ) )
                return $post_id;

            if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
                return $post_id;

            $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

            if ( ! current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ) )
                return $post_id;

            foreach ( (array) $this->fields as $meta_key => $meta_field ) {

                $meta_field['id'] = $meta_key;

                // White label field types
                if ( ! in_array( $meta_field['type'], $this->supported_fields ) )
                    continue;

                $post_value = isset( $_POST[ $meta_key ] ) ? $_POST[ $meta_key ] : '';
                $new_value = $this->sanitize_value( $post_value, $meta_field );
                $old_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );

                if ( ( $new_value || 0 == $new_value ) && $new_value != $old_value )
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_value, $old_value );
                elseif ( '' == $new_value && $old_value )
                    delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_value );
            }

            do_action( 'theux_metabox_api_save_metabox', $post_id, $post );
        }

        // Sanitize metabox value.
        function sanitize_value( $new_value, $field ) {

            if ( ! isset( $field['sanit'] ) )
                $field['sanit'] = '';

            switch ( $field['sanit'] ) {

                case 'int' :
                    return is_array( $new_value ) ? array_map( 'intval', $new_value ) : intval( $new_value );
                    break;

                case 'absint' :
                    return is_array( $new_value ) ? array_map( 'absint', $new_value ) : absint( $new_value );
                    break;

                case 'email' :
                    return is_array( $new_value ) ? array_map( 'sanitize_email', $new_value ) : sanitize_email( $new_value );
                    break;

                case 'url' :
                    return is_array( $new_value ) ? array_map( 'esc_url_raw', $new_value ) : esc_url_raw( $new_value );
                    break;

                case 'bool' :
                    return (bool) $new_value;
                    break;

                case 'color' :
                    return $this->sanitize_hex_color( $new_value );
                    break;

                case 'html' :
                    if ( current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) )
                        return is_array( $new_value ) ? array_map( 'wp_kses_post', $new_value ) : wp_kses_post( $new_value );
                    else
                        return is_array( $new_value ) ? array_map( 'wp_strip_all_tags', $new_value ) : wp_strip_all_tags( $new_value );
                    break;

                case 'nohtml' :
                    return is_array( $new_value ) ? array_map( 'wp_strip_all_tags', $new_value ) : wp_strip_all_tags( $new_value );
                    break;

                default :
                    return apply_filters( 'theux_metabox_api_sanitize_option', $new_value, $field, $setting );
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Sanitize hex color (taken from WP core).
        function sanitize_hex_color( $color ) {

            if ( '' === $color )
                return '';

            if ( preg_match('|^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$|', $color ) )
                return $color;

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * Enqueue helper functions. 
         * These functions will load the necessary javascript code.
         */

        // Color picker.
        public function color_picker_js() {

            echo '<script>';
            echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function($){';
            echo '$(".hd-color-picker").wpColorPicker();';
            echo '});';
            echo '</script>';

        } // End of function color_picker_js()

        // Upload image.
        public function upload_js() {
            echo '<script>';
            echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function($){';
            echo '$("body").on("click", ".hd-upload-button", function(e) {';
            echo 'e.preventDefault();';
            echo 'var upload_input = $(this).siblings(".hd-upload-input"),';
            echo 'hd_uploader;';
            echo 'if (hd_uploader) {';
            echo 'hd_uploader.open();';
            echo 'return;';
            echo '}';
            echo 'hd_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({';
            echo 'title: "Upload Media",';
            echo 'button: {';
            echo 'text: "Select",';
            echo '},';
            echo 'multiple: false';
            echo '});';
            echo 'hd_uploader.on("select", function() {';
            echo 'var media_file = hd_uploader.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();';
            echo 'upload_input.val(media_file.url);';
            echo '});';
            echo 'hd_uploader.open();';
            echo '});';
            echo '});';
            echo '</script>';
        } // End of function upload_js()


    } // TheUx_Metabox_API end
}; // class_exists check
```

A example how to use:

```
$layoutimg = array(
    'default'       => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/'.'mb-default.png',
    'one-col'       => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/'.'mb-1c.png',
    'two-col-left'  => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/'.'mb-2cl.png',
    'two-col-right' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/'.'mb-2cr.png'
);

// ========
// = Post =
// ========

$example_options_post = array(
    'metabox_title' =>  __('Layout Options','domain'),// Metabox Title
    'metabox_id'    => 'post_metabox',   // Unique metabox id. it is alphanumeric and does not contains spaces.
    'post_type'     => 'post',       // Post Type : you can also define as array. array( 'post', 'page' )
    'context'       => 'normal',                    // Metabox Context. Should be any of these 'normal', 'advanced' or 'side'
    'priority'      => 'high',                      // Metabox Priority. Should be any of these 'high', 'core', 'default' or 'low',
);

$example_fields_post = array(
    'hd_radio_meta' => array(
        'title'   => __('Layout','domain'),
        'type'    => 'radio_image',
        'choices' => $layoutimg,
        'desc'    => '<em>'.__('Select the layout you want on this specific page.','domain').'</em>',
        'sanit'   => 'nohtml',
    )   
);

$example_metabox_post = new TheUx_Metabox_API( $example_options_post, $example_fields_post );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems on the line no 279 of metabox class api definition, below is your code:

```
'<img src="'.$label.'" class="optionimg '.$selected_value.'" onclick="document.getElementById(\
''.$field['id'].$choices.'\').checked=true" style="display:inline-block;" /><input type="radio" 
name="%s" id="%s" value="%s" style="display:none;"/>',
```

`$choices` is not defined variable in the scope (error thrown by WAMP), I think you should replace `$field['id'].$choices` with `$value` as in below code:

```
'<img src="'.$label.'" class="optionimg '.$selected_value.'" onclick="document.getElementById(\
''.$value.'\').checked=true" style="display:inline-block;" /><input type="radio"
name="%s" id="%s" value="%s" style="display:none;"/>',
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately is not that.

Comment: ok, but I actually tried your code with Testing Environment of WordPress in local, there does not seem any other problem.